# moto cognito sign_up function not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, moto

when using `pytest.fixtures` and `mock_cognitoidp`:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def cognito(aws_credentials):
    import moto
    with moto.mock_cognitoidp():
        yield boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name='us-east-1') 

def test_cognito(cognito):
    client_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
    value = str(uuid.uuid4)
    user_pool_id = cognito.create_user_pool(PoolName=str(uuid.uuid4()))["UserPool"]["Id"]
    user_pool_client_id = cognito.create_user_pool_client(
        UserPoolId=user_pool_id, ClientName=client_name, CallbackURLs=[value]
    )['UserPoolClient']['ClientId']
    Username=str(uuid.uuid4())
    UserAttributes=[
        {"Name":"full_name",
        'Value':"Satej Sarker"}
    ]
    obj={
        "ClientId": user_pool_client_id,
        "Username":Username,
        "Password":'satejsarker'
    }
    user=cognito.sign_up(ClientId=user_pool_client_id,
         Username=username,
         Password="abc1234"
```

its giving me error like `sign_up not implemented yet`

but working with other module perfectly . and also working this code in real aws environment

Answer (score 0):

This method is not implemented in the moto library.

[here](https://github.com/spulec/moto/issues/2150) is the open github issue for the same.

It is working in live aws because in that case it is not using moto.

Answer (score 0):

This method wasn't implemented back then, but it is available as of Moto 1.3.16 (released Sept 9, 2020).

See the ChangeLog here: https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md